# When I try to print a page I created using jQuery Mobile, it always prints an extra blank page. How can I stop this?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, printing

When I try to print a page that I created using jQuery Mobile, all the pages print fine, but there was always 1 extra page that prints with nothing on it but the word "loading". I figured it could be hidden by using CSS, so I created a print style sheet and added the following to it:

```
.ui-loading,
.ui-icon-loading,
.ui-loading .ui-loader,
.ui-loader,
.ui-loader-default,
.ui-loader-verbose,
.ui-loader-default,
.ui-loader-verbose,
.ui-loader .ui-icon,
.ui-loader-verbose,
.ui-loader-textonly,
.ui-loader-textonly,
.ui-loader-fakefix {
    display:none;
}
```

This worked to hide the word "loading", but now, the extra page that the word "loading" was on is still created. So whenever I print the page there is always 1 extra page printed blank, no matter how little text is on the first page.

Any ideas on how to stop this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with CSS or jQuery Mobile. It was being caused by another jQuery plugin I was calling. Removed the call to that plugin and everything works fine now.

Comment: Which plugin was it? I'm going through hell making printing work properly from jQuery Mobile

Comment: It would be useful to know which plugin was disabled that you successfully fixed your issue with?